# rails3 and rspec2: no route matches error (while it works in the app)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2

In my `routes.rb` i have the following:

```
get 'home/index'
root :to => 'home#index'
```

If i run `rake routes | grep home` you see

```
home_index GET    /home/index(.:format)      {:action=>"index", :controller=>"home"}
root              /(.:format)                {:action=>"index", :controller=>"home"}
```

So, in my `application.html.haml` I have a link to the `root_path`, which nicely converts to

```
{:controller => "home", :action => :index}
```

But in every spec i run, i get the error:

```
No route matches {:controller=>"home"}
```

While if i run the application in development, everything renders
without any problem and is clickable correctly.

Does anybody have any clues as to what i did wrong?

I should add that the rails application is in the process of being
migrated from rails 2.3.11 to rails 3.
I must have overlooked something, but i can't see what.

[EDIT: more findings]

I have been trying out more stuff. The test run perfectly fine in Rubymine, or if i use the command-line and type

```
rspec spec/controllers/users_controller/*.spec.rb
```

But they do not work if I use

```
rake spec
```

What is the difference? I have deleted the `lib/tasks/rspec.rake` file (which was generated for rspec1) and i can see that the correct command is executed:

```
bundle exec rspec
```

So I am a bit at a loss here.

[EDIT: more testing]

When running

```
rspec spec/controller/**/*_spec.rb
```

my tests fail, when running

```
rspec spec/controller/accounts_controller/*_spec.rb
```

At the top of my files, i have the following:

```
describe AccountsController do
```

I added the type explicitly:

```
describe AccountsController, :type => :controller do
```

But that had no effect.

Does anybody have any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it! It took me a while, eventually I diffed the log-files that see what happens differently.

Apparently I have on spec file, where we try to test a baseclass. Inside that spec we define a new controller that derives 
from that baseclass, with a dummy index method.

And also we need the routes, so inside that spec the following code was to be found:

```
ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
end
```

and somehow this spec was always run first. This effectively clears the whole routing configuration i guess.

Not sure if this change is caused by rails3 or rspec2, anyway the majority of my tests are now working, just need to fix this one
test now.

Answer (score 0):

try to add this line to your routes

```
resources :home, :controller => :home
```

Comment: Hi @fl00r, thank you for your tip. It does not change anything for me. Actually i have `get 'home/index'` inside the routes (which is enough for me) (i edited my question accordingly to make that clearer). As I said the application is working, it is just while doing `rake spec` that it fails.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have to be more specific:

```
get 'home/index' => 'home#index'
```

Comment: From the documentation: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#http-verb-constraints I have the feeling it should rspec related, as the app itself is working.

Comment: I don't doubt that it's working. I'm just wondering if Rspec might have some issue with the shorthand… But I'm really just guessing.